# How to never "allow this device to access photos and videos"?

Tags: iphone, usb, charging

I have an iPhone at work, and I charge it by connecting it to my work laptop (Windows 7) via USB. Every damn time I do this, the phone asks me to `Allow this device to access photos and videos?` with the choices `Allow` and `Don't allow`.

**I want to say `never allow` because I don't want any data connection** at all but Apple has not provided this useful choice. What workaround can I use?

Note: I would just use a wall charger instead but there are no power sockets in my workspace.

---

added: The phone is listed as an `Unspecified` device under `Devices and printers`. When I open the properties, it just says `This device is working properly.` and I am not allowed to update the drivers. See screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Just noticed you updated your question. Did you try going into the Device Manager, as opposed to Devices and Printers?

Comment: I tried that too but it's the same dialogs that open. Also, I got this message: https://i.imgur.com/FmkBdj9.png

Comment: Ah, so is the Windows 7 Laptop a work laptop that's been given to you by your employer? If so you will need to have their IT person/dept follow the steps I outlined in my answer. On the other hand, if you can log in to an Admin account, then you'd be able to update the driver software. I've seen this issue on Windows 7 before and this usually resolves it.

Answer (score 3):

You don't specify, but I'm guessing you're using a Windows laptop. It's actually an issue on the Windows side of things, because what you're getting the wrong message. That is, if you're supposed to get any message, it should be the *Trust this computer* message.

The way to fix this (assuming you are in fact on Windows), is to:

1. Go to your Start menu and open Control Panel
2. Click on device manager
3. You should see a list of device types with arrows to the left of their names
4. Find the one with iPhone listed under it (usually it'll be under the Portable Devices category, but not always)
5. Right-click on iPhone and select Update Driver Software...
6. Click browse and navigate to the following location:

   `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Apple\Mobile Device Support\Drivers`
7. Select it and it *should* load the driver

**NOTES:**

- I've tried giving you generic instructions as it's not clear what version of Windows you're using.
- You should have your iPhone connected in order for Windows to see the device.
- Note that you may get the *Trust this computer* message on your iPhone, but once you opt to trust it then you should be fine to go.

Comment: Thank you; I added above that the laptop runs Windows 7.

Comment: This didn't work for me, probably because my Windows iTunes version was much older than my iPhone. After I upgraded it, the phone started giving the "Trust this computer" message with no further action required.

Comment: Does this require iTunes installed for the driver to be available?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen In terms of having drivers available at either `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Apple\Mobile Device Support\Drivers` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Apple\Mobile Device Support\Drivers` (depending on the version of Windows), then yes. The iTunes installer *should* install them in one of those locations. In terms of Windows *seeing* the iPhone in Device Manager, in theory it shouldn't need to have had iTunes installed (this is hit/miss and depends on a whole range of factors).

Comment: Not sure if anyone else said this yet but after I installed iTunes this annoying message finally went away.

Comment: Windows10 work computer: 
I just want to be able to charge the phone - without the @$% "Allow this.."
In Step 5, above,I didn't find a driver. 
I don't want iTunes. 
So, in Step 5, I right clicked and said 'Disable Device'.
Now no message on phone, but I still get a charge.

Comment: Thanks @Ron, that's also exactly what I wanted, without the Apple/iTunes bloat.

Comment: Thanks @Ron (me). A software update put me back in the same boat. I knew there was a fix. So I googled and here it is - provided by... me!   :)

Comment: FYI, Disabling Device also turned off charging, at least for me. Also on Windows 10 Enterprise

Comment: Thanks @Ron, yours should be the accepted answer.